# What is the mean transaction size and average number of transactions per block on the Ethereum blockchain?

Tags: transactions, blocks, statistics

I found an [April 7, 2017 post on Bitcoin Stack Exchange](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/10457/what-is-the-number-of-transactions-in-a-block) saying that

> Over roughly the past two months, the mean transaction size was about
>   506 bytes, and the average count of transactions per block was 1,956.
>   Current figures can be found here: [Tradeblock Historical Data](https://tradeblock.com/bitcoin/historical/1w-f-tsize_per_avg-01101-txs_blk_avg-01071)

I followed the link to see if I could find that sama data for Ethereum but could not locate it. Does anyone know the answer (or how / where to find it), and how it has evolved over time?

Comment: Idk where to find the already-gathered information, but [etherscan](https://etherscan.io/blocks?p=1) has info on all the blocks, including the transaction count within each block, but I don't see any information like averages, or even transaction sizes so I didn't want to post this as a full answer.

Answer (score 2):

There is some info and calculus here [What is the size (bytes) of a simple Ethereum transaction versus a Bitcoin transaction?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/30175/what-is-the-size-bytes-of-a-simple-ethereum-transaction-versus-a-bitcoin-trans?rq=1)
 that there is around 75 trx per block. I found some other that says there is 150 trx per block. So i guess it is somewhere in that space.

About the block size, there is also info in link above it is 15kb per block.

Answer (score 1):

If you are interested in aggregated stats this site offers quite an interesting mix of statistical functions to explore both transactions and block size https://bitinfocharts.com:

- [transaction
  stats](https://bitinfocharts.com/comparison/transactions-eth-sma7.html])
- [blocks
  stats](https://bitinfocharts.com/comparison/size-eth-sma7.html)

Comment: Thanks, Jakub, that's a very interesting site and I bookmarked it.  It does not answer my question though!  Could you possibly hyperlink the url in your answer so people can click on it easily (right now you have to copy paste).  I tried to do that myself but I am told I need to change at least six characters to justify an edit, so could not do it.  Given you are the author, you won't have that problem.

Comment: No problem, I'm glad to help :)