# What is it that allows Ethereum process a larger amount of transctions per second than Bitcoin?

Tags: transactions, bandwith

From a point of view of a developer: what is it that allows Ethereum process a larger amount of transactions per second than Bitcoin can? Is it more optimized polished code? Is it something on a more fundamental level that doesn't have to do with code but with architecture of the blockchain?

The question is about both versions 1.0 and 2.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The performance of bitcoin is limited by the frequency of block generation - an average of about 10 minutes and the maximum block size, which can now be up to 2 MB, which roughly corresponds to a maximum of 6000 transactions. Accordingly, its performance is about 10 tpc. The public Ethereum now has about 20 tps. So, there is no particular advantage.

Comment: `The performance of bitcoin is limited by the frequency of block generation` - what's the frequency limited by?

Comment: This is a purely configurational limitation - on the one hand, it ensures the stability of the network synchronization, on the other hand, the economy inherent in the concept of the Bitcoin project.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it something on a more fundamental level that doesn't have to do with code but with architecture of the blockchain?

Yes.

Average current block time:

- Ethereum: ~13 seconds
- Bitcoin: ~10-11 minutes

(Block times are by design, set in the protocols. There's some variation, but generally currently hovering around these values.)

Average current block size:

- [Ethereum](https://blockchair.com/ethereum/charts/average-block-size?interval=1m): ~45 kB.
- [Bitcoin](https://blockchair.com/bitcoin/charts/average-block-size?interval=1m): ~1.3 MB.

(Again, variable. These are the current averages. Relative block sizes are by design and can fluctuate within certain limits.)

Calculated data throughput:

- Ethereum: 10.8 MB/hour
- Bitcoin: 7.8 MB/hour

Average current transaction size (variable):

- Ethereum: (basic 21,000 gas transfer<sup>1</sup>) [~100 B](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/39033/52)
- [Bitcoin](https://charts.bitcoin.com/btc/chart/transaction-size#5ma4): ~1 kB

Given these current average values, and noting that they can vary, the current ball-park transaction throughput can be calculated as:

- Ethereum: ~108,000 / hr ==> ~30 tps (<sup>1</sup>[observed data](https://blockchair.com/ethereum/charts/transactions-per-second) is a lower tps, as not all transactions are basic 21,000 gas transfers)
- Bitcoin~: ~7800 / hr ==> ~2.2 tps (generally matches [this data](https://blockchair.com/bitcoin/charts/transactions-per-second))